# style table or page

Tags: html, css, html-table

Here is what I have done for the Employment history of HTML CV:

```
<h2>EMPLOYMENT HISTORY</h2>
<div id="Employment">
 <table>
   <tr>
     <td>Job title, &nbsp;Company, Location</td>
     <td>City</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Date</td>
     <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
 <ul >
   <li>task1</li>
   <li>task2</li>
   <li>task3</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

But this  ain't tidy nor professional and cant seem know how to push the job **location** to the far right now that it is inside a table. But I only thing I want is, that section to look like this:

```
 EMPLOYMENT HISTORY

 Customer Service Assistant, LADBROKES                        LONDON
 Fev 2018-
    - Description one
    - Description two
    - Description three

 Intern Research Assistant, MILLENIUM                        LONDON
 Jun 2017- Sept 2017
    - Description one
    - Description two
    - Description three
```

I also a have problem with my bullet points. I want to give them some margins but it fails. Here is what I have in my CSS:

```
ul {
   list-style-type:none;
}

ul li{
   margin-right: 1dpx;
}
```

Comment: why table ? why not div ? your html code and requirement is not matching.

Comment: @aviboy2006 so, you mean location should be in a div.? I wanted to have it in a table because I thought I would be easily have the space in all jobs in that section.

Comment: table spacing and margin padding will not so easy. Add your code which you want. Div will more control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move the "job location" to the right, apply `width: 100%;` to the `table` element so that the table gets full width:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h2>EMPLOYMENT HISTORY</h2>
<div id="Employment">
 <table>
   <tr>
     <td>Job title, &nbsp;Company, Location</td>
     <td>City</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Date</td>
     <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
 <ul >
   <li>task1</li>
   <li>task2</li>
   <li>task3</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: BRILLIANT, I DID NOT THINK OF IT. however I achieved it by having  location within a `span` in a paragraph and changing it in css.
like this `<p>Data Scientist, &nbsp;GLOBALDATA <span id='location'>LONDON</span>`